# &member to const member

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I get some errors. I need pass a member to a **const** member with operator =.
I don't know what is error, my function declaration is:

```
template<class I> forceinline
void OverweightValues<I>::init(int t,
                        SharedArray<int>& elements0,
                        SharedArray<int>& weights0,
                        I& i) {
{..}
//both are declared as 'const SharedArray<int> elements, weights;'
//but elements0 and weights0 not is const
elements = elements0; 
weights = weights0;
```

When I compile get the error:

```
In line(16): no operator "=" matches these operands operand types are: const SharedArray<int> = SharedArray<int>
In line(17): no operator "=" matches these operands operand types are: const SharedArray<int> = SharedArray<int>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you could assign to `elements` and `weights`, in what sense would they be `const`ant?

Comment: I, really, don't know, this class has been declared in the library of Gecode. I change the compiler and compile again and get this error

Answer (score 1):

`const` members can only be set during creation.  You'll need to use the constructor initializer list rather than two-phase construction.  (Even the constructor body cannot assign them)

Comment: How can I call the constructor in this function? I try to overload the operator = but doesn't work, or I wrote the wrong code

Answer (score 0):

As @Ben Voigt mentioned, you can only initialize a const in the constructor initialization list. This is because, by the time the control reaches the constructor body all the class members are already created by the compiler using the default constructor.

Hence, member initialization within the constructor body will actually invoke the assignment constructor which cannot be done for constants, references or objects for which default constructor is not available.